# ajax upload file formdata looks empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Does not send to php anything. And When I tried to show results on form data it looks empty.

My Form:

```
    <form id="uploadform1236-1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="uploadprove('uploadform1236-1', event, 'post.php?action=uploadprove');">
<input name="picture" id="file-upload1236-1" class="" type="file">
<input name="testx" id="xxx1" class="" value="test1236" type="text">
<button id="uploadbutton1236-1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">ttt</button>

</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function uploadprove(id, e, url) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var uploadform = $('#' + id)[0];
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById(id)); //also tried to put uploadform variable here
        alert(uploadform.toSource()); // results are ({0:{},1:{},2:{}}) It sees that 3 elements in form
        alert(formData.toSource()); // results are ({})
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            ContentType: false,
            ProcessData: false,
            success: function (data) {


                alert(data);


            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: You are selecting the input, not the file in the input

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean can you show me on codes please what need to fix?

Comment: documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: I changed the id to "file-upload1236-1" in onSubmit function. Now not working at all, not giving me any alerts. @epascarello

Comment: Did you not read the link, you need to read the file inside of the input....  line 7 in the link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fields `ContentType` and `ProcessData` are wrong they are `contentType` and `processData`

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
})
```